# how do I save a text files by group using the Area Code of the Account Number?

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm new on using Macro/VBA in Excel and I was tasked to create a macro that would generate a sorted data and will save a `.txt`  file by group base of the Area Codes on the account number.

Here's an example of the data: 17 is one of the many area codes we have, and the remaining numbers are the account number.
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyUQ3.png)

This is my code when generating files, but this code saves all of the data separately and not by group base on the area code of the Account number:

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A5:J" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In dataRange
        paymentNum = Left(cell.Value, 2)

        If dict.Exists(paymentNum) Then
            dict(paymentNum) = dict(paymentNum) & vbCrLf & cell.Value
        Else
            dict.Add paymentNum, cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    Set sortedKeys = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        sortedKeys.Add key
    Next key
    sortedKeys.Sort

    For Each key In sortedKeys
        fileName = "Group_" & key & ".txt" 

        Open fileName For Output As #1 

        Print #1, dict(key) 

        Close #1
    Next key

    MsgBox "Groups saved as text files.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

This is the result of my code:
[Sample Result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgPjU.jpg)
[Sample Generated Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfwat.png)

As you can see, it didn't even save the data correctly.

And this is the result that I'm hoping to achieve:
[sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uemFQ.jpg)

Any help for improvement is appreciated!

Comment: Questions about your expected output: Why are area codes are different (00 and 01) in the first text file (00-1111-111)? The text files' name is from its first row. The name includes not only area code but also account number. Is it right?  btw, 
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). 

Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sorting table before export to text file
- Use Dictionary object to track the different area code

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Sort method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, sFilename As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Dim iFile As Long, sTxt As String
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    ' get last row#
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A5", "J" & lastRow)
    ' sort table
    rngData.Sort Key1:=rngData.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        ' get area code
        sKey = Left(arrData(i, 1), 2)
        If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            sFilename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group_" & sKey & ".txt"
            If iFile > 0 Then Close #iFile ' colse text file
            iFile = FreeFile
            Open sFilename For Output As #iFile ' open a new text file
            objDic(sKey) = ""
        End If
        ' concate data in a row
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            sTxt = sTxt & vbTab & arrData(i, j)
        Next
        ' write data to text file
        Print #iFile, Mid(sTxt, 2)
        sTxt = ""
    Next i
    If iFile > 0 Then Close #iFile
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! this work great for me. Do you have an idea how can i save all the group files into a specific folder?

Comment: Change `sFilename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group_" & sKey & ".txt"` to `sFilename =  "D:\Data\Group_" & sKey & ".txt"`

Comment: After I changed it, there was an error in Ln 24, Col 28. What seems the issue? thank you!

Comment: The specific folder doesn't exist.